# Does salesforce provide autoscaling feature in cloud solution?

Tags: force

Like AWS, does salesforce provide autoscaling?

Answer (score 3):

The Force.com platform is not a general-purpose containerized cloud service, like AWS or Heroku. As such, autoscaling does not apply with the same meaning to Salesforce CRM/Force.com.

As a platform-as-a-service, Salesforce does handle load balancing and multitenant resource allocation for you. However, your Salesforce application does not scale across containers like on lower-level cloud platforms, and you are always responsible for building your application to respect the governor limits imposed by the platform to ensure that its multitenant nature is preserved and performance is not impacted for other customers.